# Time difference based on first and last values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a col1  index of family , col2 index of persons in each family, col3 index of trip of each person, col4 index of tour of each person,  col5 and col6 start and end time of activity how I can make a new column corresponding to each tour of each person in each household whose start time is start time of first trip and end time is end time of last trip?

here is an example

```
 family    persons    trip    tour   start time   end time
   1      1        1        1         3         8:45
   1      1        2        1       8:45        13:30
   1      1        3        1       13:30       15
   1      1        4        1      15:00        15:30
   1      1        5        2      20:00        22:00
   1      1        6        2      22:00       8:30
   1      2        1        1       3:00        8:00
   1      2        2        1      8:00        17:00
   1      2        3        1      17:00       24:00
   1      3        1        1       8:00       23:00
   1      3        2        1        23:00      24:00
```

first person has 2 tours,and 6 trips. in first tour first trip start at 3:00 and last trip ends at 15:30 , and in second tour start time is at 20:00 and last trip ends at 8:30!

second person has 1 tour and 3 trips. in this tour start time of first trip is at 3 and last trip ends at 24:00.

third person has 1 tour and 2 trips, start time of first trip is at 8 am and last trip's end time is at 24:00

So I need the following data as a output

```
  family    persons    trip    tour   start time   end time
     1      1        1        1         3         15:30
     1      1        5        2        20:00        8:30
     1      2        1        1        3:00        24:00
     1      3        1        1        8:00        24:00
```

so for each tour we have a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, your `starttime` and `endtime` are not in standard format and also it contains various formats, we first need to bring them into standard format. We can do that using `lubridate::parse_date_time` by specifying various formats that the column can take. Once, we have that we can `group_by` `family`, `persons` and `tour` and select the min and max value of start and end time respectively.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starttime, endtime), 
            list(new = ~lubridate::parse_date_time(., c("%H:%M", "%H")))) %>%
  group_by(family, persons, tour) %>%
  summarise(starttime = starttime[which.min(starttime_new)], 
            endtime = endtime[which.max(endtime_new)])

#  family persons  tour starttime endtime
#   <int>   <int> <int> <fct>     <fct>  
#1      1       1     1 3         15:30  
#2      1       1     2 20:00     22:00  
#3      1       2     1 3:00      24:00  
#4      1       3     1 8:00      24:00
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(family = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), persons = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), trip = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), tour = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), starttime = structure(c(7L, 
10L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 6L), .Label = c("13:30", 
"15:00", "17:00", "20:00", "22:00", "23:00", "3", "3:00", "8:00", 
"8:45"), class = "factor"), endtime = structure(c(10L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("13:30", "15", "15:30", 
"17:00", "22:00", "23:00", "24:00", "8:00", "8:30", "8:45"), class = 
"factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```